# Echo Python variable in shell command

Tags: python, bash, popen

I have the following Python function which interacts with Bash.

How do I get it to echo out the value of file1 and file2 using `call` or `Popen`? So something along the lines of `echo $file1 file2` but executed from Python onto a Bash terminal? My script currently compares the content of both files, but I want to make sure that the correct files are being compared.

```
def compareFiles(file1, file2)  
     result = Popen("diff " + file1 + " " + file2 + " | wc -l", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
     if int(result) > 0:
         raise Exception("Error found")
     else:
         return 0
```

So I know I have to do something like `call("echo  file1 file2", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)`, but it doesn't work. What is the correct format?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, and it isn't clear how the code in your question is relevant. It also contains syntax errors.

Comment: Trying to execute a shell command from Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the file paths right there as arguments to the function:  `file1` and `file2`.

Open and read them in Python.  There's no reason to shell out if you don't have to.

```
with open(file1, "rb") as f:
    file1_data = f.read()

with open(file2, "rb") as f:
    file2_data = f.read()

print(file1_data)
print(file2_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the values of the filenames, use:

```
print(file1 + " " + file2)
```